# Change colour of highlight for matching words in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

How do you change the colour of the matching words that are highlighted when you select a word in Notepad++?

Depending on style, matching word highlights can be almost invisible.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

Settings > Style Configurator > Global Styles > Smart HighLighting

Comment: Very much Thank you! I've been having hard time with that for months

Comment: Also don't forget to uncheck "Match whole word only" from Kris Walsh's answer

Answer (score 14):

For version 6.2.3, these are the steps...

> Settings > Style Configurator

From the pop-up window, select `Smart HighLighting` from the `Style` select list, and then set the colour on the right hand side.

[image]

Also, make sure you have *Smart Highlighting* enabled...

> Settings > Preferences > Misc

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Style Configurator -> Global Styles -> Selected text colour.

Comment: This is basically going to change the color of the selected text.

Answer (score 7):

If appropriate, also make sure "Match whole word only" is **not** checked.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, perfect answer

Answer (score 0):

In version 6.9 the way to access smart highlighting preferences changed:

`Settings > Preferences > MISC > Smart HighLighting`

Comment: That's to turn it on and off. Colors are still in the Style Configurator.